# Determine a list of dictionary from a list of path

Tags: python, dictionary

Hy guys, I'm new to python and I have to solve this problem. I have a file in which are collected some variable paths, like these for example:

```
Simulation/Task Information Variables/Periodic Task 1/Task Call Counter

Simulation/Task Information Variables/Periodic Task 1/Task Turnaround Time

Simulation/Task Information Variables/RTILINMM_MAIN_LINID1INTERRUPT/Task Call Counter

Simulation/Application Startup Variables/Scaled Time Interval

Model/CON/Bus_Selector_Mapping/Bus\nCreator/Out1{SubArray1}

Model/NEW_CPT_TA/CAN/DCTM/ESS/Value

Labels/BCM{Occurence4}{SubArray14}

Labels/Ign4{SubArray6}

BusSystems/CON/Master/GE/RX/GE_ID
```

I have to produce this output thats it a list of dictionaries like the following one:

`[{PAR1: [Simulation, Model, Labels, BusSystems]},{PAR2: [Simulation, [Task Information Variables,Application Startup Variables]}, {PAR3: [CON, Model, [NEW_CPT_TA]}` ...

The first dictionary contains the list of parents, the second of the list contains sons of the first element in `{PAR1: [Simulation, Model, Labels, BusSystems]}` with label `Simulation`. I'm sorry for errors in formatting but this is my first post here. Thanks to all for helping me.

Comment: It's not clear how the data structure should be built. Can you include the _entire exact_ result you want for the given input?

Comment: Also, you have a `'\n'` in the middle of the fifth path.